# How to refresh a particular tree node on a button click in dojo?

Tags: dojo

I am having a lazy load tree using QueryReadStore and ForestStoreModel. I populated my tree and expanded some of nodes. Now in backend some more data is added for a particular node. I have to refresh that node and display new child elements under it on one button click.

I am wondering how to do that as I am not getting any such method or any example on net. When I have gone through stores API I found a method onChildrenChange() which says it will update the store if any changes happen in backend. I tried this method also but did not get any success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Extend / add this function to your tree:

```
    reloadNode:function(nodeId){

        nodes=this.getNodesByItem({"id":nodeId});//Create dummyitem&search for nodes
        if (nodes[0]!==undefined) { // Is there a node with this id ?
        nodes[0]._loadDeferred=false; // Reload the first node with this id
        this._expandNode(nodes[0]);//this = "dijit/Tree"

        }
    }
```